# Attempting to backup to remote NAS but access is denied

Tags: sql-server, backup, connectivity, authentication

I was attempting to use Ola Hallengren's scripts to backup to a remote NAS, but it was failing and not giving any direct errors, so I tried doing it manually using Server Management Studio and got the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> ------------------------------
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
> batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ------------------------------
>
> The operating system returned the error '0x80070005(Access is
> denied.)' while attempting 'SvlPathDoesPathExist' on
> '\Dl-nas-01\LOCAL FILE BACKUP\OLASQL'. The statement has been
> terminated. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3634)
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.2002&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3634&LinkId=20476
>
> ---

Now, the account I am signed into has `FULL` permission and access to that share, my connection is my `domain\myaccount`, and from the VM I can even put `\\Dl-nas-01\LOCAL FILE BACKUP\OLASQL` into a folder browser and access it.

Does SQL Server run these from a different account I don't know about? Backing up to a local location works fine, what's the solution? I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned this is a NAS, but this doesn't look like a valid network path:

```
\Dl-nas-01\LOCAL FILE BACKUP\OLASQL
```

Try using two slashes at the beginning, like this:

```
\\Dl-nas-01\LOCAL FILE BACKUP\OLASQL
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you logged in to the server with a login and it got full permission to it. That doesn't mean that SQL server service running under the same. So make sure that the service login is having rights to access the folder. You can find the SQL server service login by doing the below steps.

Access your SQL Server configurartion manager mentioned in the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21759718/1421050)

To open SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the Search charm, under Apps, type:

> SQLServerManager14.msc for [SQL Server 2017] or
>
> SQLServerManager13.msc for [SQL Server 2016] or
>
> SQLServerManager12.msc for [SQL Server 2014] or
>
> SQLServerManager11.msc for [SQL Server 2012] or
>
> SQLServerManager10.msc for [SQL Server 2008], and

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Right click on your SQL service and check under `Log On` to find the account highlighted above in the picture.

Comment: This was part of the problem, thank you so much!